# Reporting critical Event ID to email

Tags: monitoring, powershell, windows-event-log

How do you organize or implement monitoring system in your domain to monitor these critical error on your workstations and servers ?

```
Hardware Related:
7, 9, 11, 51, 52, 55 Potential HD related issue 
1053 Servers too hot. Sometimes our Air conditioning breaks.
```

Any kind of help and comments will be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks,

AWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh... I keep posting a link to OSSEC, but it'll fit your needs:

http://www.ossec.net

OSSEC's rules can be easily tweaked to alert based on Windows event sources/IDs.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so i must install that agent in all of my domain workstation and server, is there any automated way ?